# jQuery html() with preserving data()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html node and another one just like it in structure with minor differences. (both are very complex nodes) both nodes have a lot of `jQuery.data` set on their children. One node is in the document and the other is just a fragment in the memory.

I want to replace the content of the node in the DOM with the fragment one, **and preserve** all the `jQuery.data` along with the fragment, but it just get lost using html()..how can I preserve it?

Comment: I know that you said that you are a complex structure, but I tested and it is working with both, data are not removed after text update : http://jsbin.com/adequl/1/

Comment: it's not just a text update, it's a massive classes update and other stuff. lets just say I want to copy a whole different dom ALONG with it's data()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid using `.html()`, use something like **[`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)** instead. This will move the DOM elements around, rather than plainly overwriting the textual HTML